# postgres - getting data by distinct targets and averaging - no luck so far

Tags: python, postgresql

**Main Question: "What is the average temperature of all my sensors currently? What is the average angle? average db level?"**

So I have a python script that loops every 15 minutes that populates a postgres table (xmldata) with data from a http get operation. This table will very likely have 1,000,000+ records. This table and data look like:

```
fieldtest2=> select * from xmldata limit 7;
 id |            time            | ddinstancename | dcchannelname | dcdintegervalue 
----+----------------------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------
  1 | 2014-02-18 12:51:00.561153 | targ_4079E741  | AD1           |             641
  2 | 2014-02-18 12:51:04.568751 | targ_40971E83  | AD1           |             641
  3 | 2014-02-18 12:51:08.535351 | targ_4079E741  | AD0           |             641
  4 | 2014-02-18 12:51:12.90712  | targ_4079E741  | AD1           |             641
  5 | 2014-02-18 12:51:16.863364 | targ_40971E83  | AD1           |             641
  6 | 2014-02-18 13:15:48.109646 | targ_40971E83  | AD0           |             589
  7 | 2014-02-18 13:15:48.463776 | targ_4079E741  | AD1           |             653
```

Now, the part I'm stuck on. I want to get the most recent dcdintegervalue from each **unique** ddinstancename (going back only an hour or two because of the size of the table), group them by dcchannelname and average the dcdintegervalue of each group. So basically for example, each "AD1" is a temperature reading. And I want to get the most recent capture of AD1 data from each unique ddinstancename. In the above example, that would be records id 5 and 7. Then I want to average their dcdintegervalues, so 641 + 653 /2 = 647 and save that average to another table, sensoraverage:

```
fieldtest2=> select * from sensoraverage;
 id | time | dcchannelname | channelaverage 
----+------+---------------+----------------
(0 rows)
```

So basically you are getting a snapshot of, right now, the average temperature of all the targets is 647, the average x angle is 111, the average db level is 234 ... etc.

I've been attempting several variations and 'dumbing it down' as I go, but the following 'hard codes' the channel currently in question, doesn't order or limit, just to try and get something working. The idea was I'd just do a separate query for each dcchannelname. But there is probably a better way. Should I split this up into several separate queries?

There will only ever be 4 distinct dcchannelname's. There could be hundreds of distinct ddinstancename's.

```
avgTemp_query = "INSERT into sensoraverage (dcChannelName, channelaverage) VALUES (('AD0'), (SELECT DISTINCT ddInstanceName, AVG(dcdIntegerValue) FROM xmldata WHERE dcChannelName='AD0'));"
```

I think from what I've read, distinct does not operate the way I'm thinking it should. 
Any guidance would be appreciated. 
Thanks
Mike

**UPDATE:** based on Lucas' answer it seems close. the problem I think I am having is around the timestamp. I'd add this as a comment to Lucas' post but it was too long...

I'm wondering if I need to re-do how I timestamp these record entries into xmldata, if that could be the problem. Here is my latest attempts ( I also tried now()::date - 100 to try to catch anything that way with no luck):

Trying a straight up match should actually only result in one result (see bottom table), but produces a full set of averages. I haven't been able to determine what values are used based on the match, to make up the averages yet. But I feel like its close. I'm sorry for the formatting but I had this all in one line for running it through my terminal...

```
fieldtest2=> WITH distinct_instances AS(
SELECT ddInstanceName 
FROM xmldata 
WHERE time = '2014-02-18 12:51:00.561153' 
GROUP BY ddInstanceName HAVING count(*) = 1) 
SELECT dcChannelName, avg(dcdintegervalue) 
FROM distinct_instances 
JOIN xmldata ON xmldata.ddInstanceName = distinct_instances.ddInstanceName 
GROUP BY dcChannelName 
ORDER BY dcChannelName;

 dcchannelname |         avg          
---------------+----------------------
 AD0           | 621.5416666666666667
 AD1           | 648.6153133797599644
 AD2           | 258.8515185601799775
 AD3           | 324.5770528683914511
(4 rows)

fieldtest2=> select * from xmldata WHERE time = '2014-02-18 12:51:00.561153';
 id |            time            | ddinstancename | dcchannelname | dcdintegervalue 
----+----------------------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------
  1 | 2014-02-18 12:51:00.561153 | targ_4079E741  | AD1           |             641
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
-- first get a set of the distinct instances within the last time period (here it is 1 hour)
-- then join that result set back to the table and group it by the channel name
WITH distinct_instances AS(
  SELECT
    ddinstancename,
  FROM xmldata
  WHERE time > now() - '1 hour'::interval
  GROUP BY ddinstancename
  HAVING count(*) = 1
)
SELECT
  dcchannelname,
  avg(dcdintegervalue)
FROM distinct_instances
JOIN xmldata ON xmldata.ddinstancename = distinct_instances.ddinstancename
GROUP BY dcchannelname
ORDER BY dcchannelname
```

Due to the join, you may want to index both `ddinstancename` and `time` to get any performance out of this query.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I tested it out and it returns zero records. I've fiddled with it and think I narrowed it down to the now() function and am wondering if its not finding time matches due to the format of 'time' in my table? the xmldata time field: "time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT statement_timestamp()". Thanks again. Mike

Comment: If I replace `> now() - '1 hour'` with a simple `= '2014-02-18 12:51:00.561153'` it will return a hit ok.

Comment: `now() - '1 hour'::interval` will return a timestamp one hour in the past, if the query worked with the timestamp you specified, then either there were no unique records in that hour it was looking in, or the data hadn't been updated.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I had tested for that and tried things like "20 days" but I think I just need to do some more testing. I will mark your answer correct. Thanks again for the assistance.